# Is there any way to apply AOP to a .NET library without using attribute decoraction?

Tags: c#, .net, aop, event-sourcing

I fully understand my question is an odd one and there may be a lot of better ways to achieve my goal so any help will be appreciated.

The basic idea is to track all changes made in runtime to certain properties of entities of certain types without modifying their code.

Let's assume I have an entity named Foo as described below:

```
class Foo
{
    private string _bar;
    public string Bar 
    { 
        get { return _bar; } 
        set 
        {
            // some logic here...
            _bar = value;
            // some logic here... 
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I want a library which allow me to write code looking like the following:

```
Hook.For<Foo>()
    .OnSet(foo => foo.Bar)
    .Action((foo, value) => 
    {
        // save the state of the foo instance along with the value passed to the setter
    });
```

I understand that the required functionality involves adding some additional build steps to modify the output assembly IL code. There is no need for the syntax to be this fluent, I don't even mind JSON or XML configuration. The main idea is not to change tons of bad legacy code of our application and use external monitoring (for debug purposes) instead.

Are there any AOP frameworks that can apply aspects like this globally, without requiring me to decorate every single property or class with attributes?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like PostSharp provides the ability to apply external aspects on existing code as described in following article: http://programmersunlimited.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/applying-aspects-to-3rd-party-assemblies-using-postsharp/

I'll go with this solution for now.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to take a look at Tyler Brinks [SNAP](https://github.com/TylerBrinks/Snap) project on GitHub: https://github.com/TylerBrinks/Snap

The framework sits on top on any number of IoC containers to inject AOP proxies on top of your classes:

```
 // Configure SNAP to look at all assemblies starting with the "ConsoleApplication1"  namespace.
// Next, tell SNAP to intercept any code decorated with a DemoLoggingAttribute by running
// an instance of the DemoLoggingInterceptor class.
SnapConfiguration.For<StructureMapAspectContainer>(c =>
    {
        // Tell SNAP to only be concerned with stuff starting with this namespace.
        c.IncludeNamespace("ConsoleApplication1*");
        // Tell SNAP to intercept any method or class decorated with    "DemoLoggingAttribute"
        // by wrapping execution in your own DemoInterceptor class.
        c.Bind<DemoLoggingInterceptor>().To<DemoLoggingAttribute>();
    });

  // Configure StructureMap as usual.
  ObjectFactory.Configure(c => c.For<ISampleClass>().Use<SampleClass>());



 // Use your own class to handle interception.  Logging is a good example.
 public class DemoLoggingInterceptor : MethodInterceptor
 {
     public override void InterceptMethod(IInvocation invocation, MethodBase method, Attribute attribute)
     {
     // Log something important here.

     // Then continue executing your method.
     invocation.Proceed();
     }
 }
```

Comment: SNAP requires attributes, and cannot be applied globally, as PostSharp can, which is what the OP asks for. However it is open source, it's a nice simple tool, it shouldn't be too hard to implement a global interceptor.